# Changing Font Size of UILabel on applying Pinch Gesture

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I am creating an app which has a `UILabel` which can be pinched, rotated. When I pinch in the `UILabel`, it gets pixelated. How can I resolve this?

Comment: what object is handling the pinching and rotation gestures?  Is it the "`UILabel`" or is it actually the view that your label object lives within?

Comment: it is the label which is handling that

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `UILabel` is property of your viewController:

```
CGFloat pinchScale = pinchGesture.scale;
pinchScale = round(pinchScale * 1000) / 1000.0;

if (pinchScale < 1) {
        self.UILabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:self.UILabel.font.fontName size:(self.UILabel.font.pointSize - pinchScale)];
}
else{
        self.UILabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:self.UILabel.font.fontName size:(self.UILabel.font.pointSize + pinchScale)];
}
```

Also, set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to YES

Comment: It is not working because the font size of the label becomes too large that make the label to go down on pinch

Comment: set adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth to YES. I've adjusted my answer too.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the rounded off scale of the pinchgesture by

```
- (void)pinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGesture
   {
     CGFloat pinchScale = pinchGesture.scale;
     pinchScale = round(pinchScale * 1000) / 1000.0;

        YourLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"your font Name" size:Actual Font size+pinchScale];


   }
```

Try this may this help.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work, try it.

```
pinchScale2 = pinchGesture.scale;
pinchScale2 = round(pinchScale2 * 1000) / 1000.0;

if (pinchScale2 < pinchScale1)
{
        self.UILabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:self.UILabel.font.fontName size:(self.UILabel.font.pointSize - pinchScale2)];
}
else
{
        self.UILabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:self.UILabel.font.fontName size:(self.UILabel.font.pointSize + pinchScale2)];
}
pinchScale1 = pinchScale2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work, try it.

```
CGFloat maxFontSize;
NSString* string = pTextLabel.text;

UIFont* pfont = [UIFont fontWithName:[pTextLabel font].fontName size:600];
[string sizeWithFont:pfont minFontSize:3 actualFontSize:&maxFontSize forWidth:pTextLabel.frame.size.width - 1 lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];


UIFont* pStampFont = [UIFont fontWithName:[pTextLabel font].fontName size:maxFontSize];
[pTextLabel setFont:pStampFont];
```